# Websphere 8.5 with Federated repositories(LDAP)

Tags: ldap, websphere

I tring configure Federated repositories for my application
After configuring and enabling Global security to Federated repositories I can login to console, but in my app `httpRequest.getUserPrincipal().getName();` returns full LDAP structure (CN=Username,ou=Users,dc=...)

How can I change it to return only CN?

Comment: I think I found it. Necessary put the cn first in the "Federated repository properties for login". Check it tomorrow :)

Comment: Yes, this is determined by the login properties. Note that you can have multiple login properties and getUserPrincipal will return the first attribute in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it. Necessary put the cn first in the "Federated repository properties for login"